# Composite Component in JSF 2.2 will not render

Tags: html, myfaces, jsf-2.2

I migrated a project from myfaces 2.1 to 2.2, and now my composite component will not render.

The page output shows:

```
<meg:megamenu menubean="ec.common.WetTopMenuBarBean@183817e" id="topMenuLevel0" />
```

Where the me:megamenu should be expanded into the rendered html.

It all worked in myfaces 2.1. Does anyone have any ideas?

The structure is basically a page, that uses a template, that ui:include another reusable content, which then uses the composite component.

The page:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/wetLayout.xhtml" >
```

The template:

```
<ui:include src="#{chosenTheme == 'intranet' ? '/sections/common/intranet/commonHeader.xhtml' : '/sections/common/commonHeader.xhtml'}" >
```

The sub section:

```
...
xmlns:meg="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components/topNav"
...
<meg:megamenu id="topMenuLevel0" menuBean="#{wetTopMenuBarBean}"    />
```

I have also tried it with both eclipse Juno and Kepler.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: But the rest of your page is being rendered properly?

Comment: Yes, everything else renders fine. Only composite components fail to render. It's as if the myfaces implementation is not reading and expanding the component.

Comment: Did you already checked if org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_ALLOW_SLASH_LIBRARY_NAME web config param is set to true? The spec says that slashes are not allowed in library by default, and in this case the libraryName is components/topNav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this in an example of my own and you are right: It is not possible to use composite components in sub directories by default. As Leonardo pointed out in a comment to the question, this is not allowed in the JSF spec.

In MyFaces, however, this behavior can be changed by setting the context parameter `org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_ALLOW_SLASH_LIBRARY_NAME` to `true`.

With this parameter set, I can use composite components in sub directories with MyFaces 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Set your namespace correctly, and it should work:

xmlns:meg="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/topNav"

Comment: Tried both the old and new namespace, both fail